# Use a variable within heredoc in PHP

Tags: php, variables, heredoc

I'm a newbie to PHP/SQL and I am trying to use a variable within a heredoc as I need to output a lot of text. I've only included the first sentence as it is enough to show the problem).

My problem is that within the heredoc, the variables (see below: `$data['game_name]` and `$data['game_owner']`) are not recognized as variables, but as plain text. How can I solve this?

```
$response = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM video_game');
while ($data = $response->fetch())
{

    echo <<<'EX'
    <p>Game: $data['game_name']<br/>
    the owner of the game is $data['game_owner']
    </p>
    EX;
}
```

Comment: you are using [NOWDOC](http://php.net/nowdoc) not HEREDOC

Comment: maybe a really dumb question, but does `EX` need to be left-justified?

Comment: @edwardsmarkf for many years already it doesn't.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Your heredoc needs a little modification (because it's actually Nowdoc!):

```
    echo <<<EX
    <p>Game: {$data['game_name']}<br/>
    the owner of the game is {$data['game_owner']}
    </p>
    EX;
```

- Heredoc identifiers (unlike nowdoc ones) cannot be quoted. `'EX'` needs to become `EX`.

  You're confusing Nowdoc with heredoc.
- Complex data types in strings must be surrounded by `{}` for them to be parsed as variables. For example, `$data['game_name']` should be `{$data['game_name']}`.
- In the obsoleted PHP versions ( before PHP 7.3) the heredoc terminator *must not* have any preceding whitespace. From the documentation:

  > The closing identifier may be indented by space or tab, in which case the indentation will be stripped from all lines in the doc string. Prior to PHP 7.3.0, the closing identifier must begin in the first column of the line.

You're mixing up heredoc and nowdoc here. You want to use **heredoc** and *not* Nowdoc because you've got variables inside your string. Heredocs are "extended" double quoted strings, whereas nowdocs are more akin to a single quoted string, in that variables are not parsed in nowdoc strings, but are in heredoc.

- More on heredoc [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).
- More on Nowdoc [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc).

Please read the documentation more carefully on these.