# PHP tag inside <<<HTML ...... HTML;

Tags: php, html

I have been stuck trying to write PHP code inside some HTML tags I set up.

I have a variable inside a `.php` file called `$content`, and I have a HTML page code inside this variable in the following way:

`$content = <<<HTML        some html code in here         HTML;`

Now, within that HTML tag I wanted to add some PHP code, tried using `<?php    .....     ?>`, however I wasn't successful with it. Can anyone help?

Comment: [Stackoverflow: Calling PHP functions within HEREDOC strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104516/calling-php-functions-within-heredoc-strings)? OR [Stackoverflow: Use variable within heredoc in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274354/use-variable-within-heredoc-in-php-sql-practice)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 4):

That's a `HEREDOC` syntax , The closing `HTML;` should be in margin else it wont work.

#### Valid Syntax

```
<?php
$somevar="Hello World";
echo <<<HTML
    <b> Hey this is some text and I am adding this variable $somevar</b>
HTML;
```

#### Invalid Syntax

```
    <?php
    $somevar="Hello World";
    echo <<<HTML
        <b> Hey this is some text and I am adding this variable $somevar</b>
      HTML; //<--- As you can see there is a leading space
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that the tags are on the right place. The issue I am having is to add php code inside those HEREDOC tags (If that is what you call it)

Comment: I think you should also wrap your variables quotes `{$somevar}`

Comment: It is not just a variable that I want to add, perhaps I wasnt very clear, but I want to add few 5 php lines of code inside those HEREDOC tags

Comment: @Jordan, Please don't do that.. doing that so will eventually land yourself in [**Code Smell**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran thanks for the opinion, but there is no way to do it, because my <<<HTML tags contain entire HTML page, which is echo by php for display, but this time inside those HEREDOC codes I have html <select></select> tags, and the <option></option> tags content I want to fetch from my database using query

Comment: @Jordan, Basically you cannot add condition checks , assignment operations done inside of `HEREDOC` syntax. They are just for quoting strings and escaping stuff. You can't write a logic inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `<script type="text/php">...</script>`

Comment: I have tried that too, wasn't successful..Good thought anyways

Answer (score 1):

With very old version of PHP, HEREDOC `<<<HTML` to open a string are not always supported.
If you use an old PHP, a workaround is to do:

```
$myvar="some html code here <a href=\"eee\">link</a>
next line of html code
".$myotherphpvar."
rest of lines"
```

Note that if you open string with ", you must escape all " for html code with `\`.

With recent PHP version you can use HEREDOC syntax. This is example of syntax:

```
    $myvar=<<<HTML
some html code here <a href="eee">link</a>
    next line of html code $myotherphpvar
    rest of lines
HTML;
```

More examples on page:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: your example is clear when I want to add a variable inside the HEREDOC tags. However, in this occasion I want to add few 5 php lines of code inside those HTML HEREDOC tags, or if I can call a function inside those HEREDOC tags, then things can become easier